# Visual Studio ImportError: No module named boto3

Tags: python, visual-studio, aws-cli

I am trying to run VS-Code to work with Python and boto3. 
but I am getting the following error

```
importError: No module named boto3
```

I am able to run python statements via VS-code but for some reason I can't get it to work with AWS.

VS-Code Extension:

```
AWS Toolkit 
Code Runner 
Python
```

MacOS CLI

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.4
aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.209 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/18.0.0 botocore/1.12.199
pip3 --version
pip 19.2.1
```

VS-Code launch.json

```
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**:
I opened a Terminal from the top menu (Terminal -> New Terminal);

in the newly opened terminal I typed:

```
pip install botocore
pip install boto3
```

After doing this, the errors I was getting for:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
```

disappeared (after closing and reopening the Python file I was editing).

**Background**:
I am new to VisualStudio Code (Version: 1.41.1 on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6) and I was having the same problem.